# Further narrow down regex character set so that one uppercase is mandatory

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long string like `aaaaa123 ** bbbbb444 ** ccccc66 ** ddDddD77 ** eeeee667` and want to grab a substring using a Regex.

What I've got so far:

`/[A-Z,a-z,0-9,_-]{7,14}/`

This should return any group of 7 to 14 characters consisting of uppercase, lowercase, digits - and _

So far so good.

However, I now want it to be more strict so that **at least one uppercase character** is mandatory. I.e. in my example only `ddDddD77` should match. How do I do that?

Comment: What programming language are you using here?

Comment: Use `\b(?=[0-9_-]*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9_-]{7,14}\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a lookahead and `\w` is supported and the word does not start or end with `-` you can assert for the length and match at least an uppercase:

```
\b(?=[\w-]{7,14}\b)[a-z0-9_-]*[A-Z][\w-]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptvyNQ/1)

Another option:

```
(?<!\S)(?=[\w-]{7,14}(?!\S))[a-z0-9_-]*[A-Z][\w-]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IhSQVs/1)

If the lookbehind is not supported, you could also opt for a capture group:

```
(?:\s|^)(?=[\w-]{7,14}(?:\s|$))([a-z0-9_-]*[A-Z][\w-]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y3eGQh/1)